# Placing session variables into html form fields - how do I make it DRY?

Tags: php, html, dry

I am writing a page using html/php to collect user information.  When the user clicks submit, it will take them to another page that they can confirm their info before it gets submitted into the system. If there is a problem, users have the option of clicking a "go back" button and editing the info.  I would like the information that they originally entered to appear in all the form fields.

```
<td> <label for="firstname"> First Name </label> </td>
<td> <input type="name" id="firstname" name="firstname" <?php if ($_SESSION[firstname]<>""){echo "value='$_SESSION[firstname]'";}?> /> </td> </tr>
<tr>
<td> <label for="lastname"> Last Name </label> </td>
<td> <input type="name" id="lastname" name="lastname" <?php if ($_SESSION[lastname]<>""){echo "value='$_SESSION[lastname]'";}?> /> *required</td> </tr>
<tr>
<td> <label for="email"> Email </label></td>
<td> <input type="email" id="email" name="email"<?php if ($_SESSION[email]<>""){echo "value='$_SESSION[email]'";}?> /> *required</td> </tr>
<tr> 
<td> <label for="phone"> Phone </label> </td>
<td> <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" <?php if ($_SESSION[phone]<>""){echo "value='$_SESSION[phone]'";}?> /> *required</td> </tr>
<tr>
<td> <label for="address1"> Address Line 1 </label> </td>
<td> <input type="text" id="address1" name="address1" <?php if ($_SESSION[address1]<>""){echo "value='$_SESSION[address1]'";}?> /> </td> </tr>
<tr>
<td> <label for="address2"> Address Line 2 </label> </td>
<td> <input type="text" id="address2" name="address2" <?php if ($_SESSION[address2]<>""){echo "value='$_SESSION[address2]'";}?> /> </td></tr>
<tr>
<td> <label for="city"> City </label> </td>
<td> <input type="text" id="city" name="city" <?php if ($_SESSION[city]<>""){echo "value='$_SESSION[city]'";}?> /> *required</td></tr>
```

How do I make this more DRY?

Comment: I would start by looking into those potential XSS vulnerabilities

Comment: You could try using a form builder - http://www.dyn-web.com/php/form_builder/code.php

Answer (score -1):

I did this very quick, this really wouldn't be the way I would do it myself but it will technically make it DRY. Remember to implement this in any classes you have. Also, sanitize the user inputs. Make improvements where you see fit.

Ignoring the fact that this doesn't implement MVC (which you should research) I would do the following:

```
<?php

instanceTd($type = 'open')
{
    switch($type){
        case 'open':
            echo '<td>';
        case 'closed':
            echo '</td>';
    }
}

displayHTML($htmlType, $property)
{
    // double quotes allow variables to be parsed by PHP with ease

    $name = $property['name'];
    $value = $property['value'];
    $label = $property['value'];
    $type = $property['type'];

    switch($htmlType)
    {
        case 'label':
            echo "<label for='$name'> $label </label>";
            exit;
        case 'input':
            echo "<input type='$type' id='$name' name='$name' value='$value'/>";
            if($property['required'] == 'true')
            {
                echo '*required';
            }
            exit;
    }
}

$array = array(
    1 => array(  // index acts as order in this case.
        'name' => 'firstname',
        'label' => 'First Name',
        'type' => 'name',
        'value' => '',
        'required' => 'true'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'name' => 'lastname',
        'label' => 'Last Name',
        'type' => 'name',
        'value' => '',
        'required' => 'true'
    ),
    3 => array(
        'name' => 'email',
        'label' => 'Email',
        'type' => 'email',
        'value' => '',
        'required' => 'true'
    ),
    4 => array(
        'name' => 'phone',
        'label' => 'Phone',
        'type' => 'tel',
        'value' => '',
        'required' => 'true'
    ),
    5 => array(
        'name' => 'address1',
        'label' => 'Address Line 1',
        'type' => 'text',
        'value' => '',
        'required' => 'false'
    ),
    6 => array(
        'name' => 'address2',
        'label' => 'Address Line 2',
        'type' => 'text',
        'value' => '',
        'required' => 'false'
    ),
    7 => array(
        'name' => 'city',
        'label' => 'City',
        'type' => 'text',
        'value' => '',
        'required' => 'true'
    )
);

//For each field you want displayed do the following.
foreach($array as $index => $property)
{

    // Check if the field has been posted, then set the value to that POST value
    if(isset($_POST[$property['name']])){
        $property['value'] = $_POST[$property['name']];
    }

    instanceTd('open');
    displayHTML('label', $property);
    displayHTML('input', $property);
    instanceTd('closed');
}
```

Comment: This code is not valid PHP *and* if it would have been it would be wide open to xss attacks.